# caught-cot merger: can "lawyer" sound like "lier"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, vowels

"law" is pronounced as `/lɑ/` if you speak with the caught-cot merger, so, logic suggests "lawyer" should sound like `/lɑjɚ/`, as "lawyer" is basically "law" + "yer"

For me, the difference between `/lɑjɚ/` and `/ˈlaɪ.ɚ/` is just the backness of `/ɑ/`.

There are however, speakers that realize the American `/ɑ/` as a central `/ä/`*, meaning that `/lɑjɚ/` is realized as `/läjɚ/` which sounds like `/ˈlaɪ.ɚ/`.

So, can "lawyer", for some speakers, can sound like "lier"?

(*I believe it's one of the northern cities vowel shifts?)

Comment: It’s probably not universal (nothing ever is), but _lawyer_ is definitely not _law_ + _yer_ for me. As a word, _law_ is /lɔː/ (with merger, /lɑː/), whereas _lawyer_ /lɔɪ.ər/, not /lɔː.jər/ and thus not affected by the ᴄᴏᴛ–ᴄᴀᴜɢʜᴛ merger. _Lawyer_ rhymes with _coyer_ (i.e., first syllable rhymes with _boy_) and has an entirely different syllable structure from _lier_ (or _liar_, which is probably the more common homophone).

Comment: @Janus: there are definitely Americans who pronounce *lawyer* as /lɔː.jɚ/ and not /lɔɪ.ɚ/. The question is whether any of these Americans have a COT-CAUGHT merger where /ɔ/ is realized as [ä], so their pronunciation is [läː.jər], which sounds a lot like /ˈlaɪ.ɚ/

Comment: It probably won't happen in the Northern Cities vowel shift. That doesn't have the COT-CAUGHT merger, so *law* is pronounced [lɒ] and not [lä] (which would be the first part of *lot*).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet For folks who pronounce *boy* with a more closed /boɪ/ not /bɔɪ/, *lawyer* becomes /loɪər/ or /lojər/. By losing the connection with *law*  /lɔː/ we think of a lawyer  as someone who does something or other with *“loys”*, whatever those are. :) See also *Tom Sawyer*, where nobody now knows there were ever once any *saws* /sɔːz/ involved in that profession because of how the more open /ɔ/ has become a more closed /o/ in Tom’s surname.

Comment: @tchrist Even for those of us who don’t have a closer /o/ vowel there, the disconnect is real—I didn’t connect _lawyer_ with _law_ until… well, until some age that I’m old enough to remember. I remember the ‘aha’ moment, so I almost certainly grasped the connection through spelling, not pronunciation.

Comment: you guys are right about the northen cities vowel shift. in those cities, ɔ -> ɑ but also ɑ -> ä so, "law" can only be lowered to läːjər. but I'm sure there are speakers that just use ä for both ɑ and ɔ . I'm not a native speaker, but that kind of accent doesn't sound implausible for me. well, I guess that even if there are speakers that pronounce "liar", "lier" and "lawyer" the same, they are not a common as I initially thought.

Comment: What @tchrist said. In mid-atlantic AmE dialect, **lawyer** rhymes with the American pronunciation (non-Frenchified) of *voyeur* with accent on the first syllable. In any AmE pronunciation of **lawyer** where the first syllable is a back vowel and is not said with the lips protruded, the first syllable glides into the palatal **y** of the second syllable, and that can make the first syllable's vowel, if the word is said quickly, sound a lot like /aI/ of **liar**. In most AmE dialects, the two words do not have an entirely different syllable structure.

Answer (score 0):

> logic suggests "lawyer" should sound like /lɑjɚ/, as "lawyer" is basically "law" + "yer"

Since when is English pronunciation logical? As [Wiktionary notes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lawyer), outside of the South *lawyer* is  pronounced in American English as /ˈlɔɪ.ɚ/ (phonemically).  *Liar,* meanwhile, is transcribed [by Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liar) as /ˈlaɪ.ɚ/; some dictionaries don't list *lier,* but [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lier) transcribes it as a homophone of *liar.* The diphthongs /ɔɪ/ and /aɪ/ are not affected by the cot-caught merger. [Wiki doesn't list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects), and I'm not aware, of any American accents that merge /ɔɪ/ and /aɪ/, so outside of the South these two are certainly not homophones.

In the Southern US, [per Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lawyer), *lawyer* can be pronounced /ˈlɔ.jɚ/. Such accents generally lack the cot-caught merger, though they may have the rod-ride merger (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_diphthongs#Rod%E2%80%93ride_merger)), which would merge /ɑ/ and /aɪ/. Hypothetically, if a speaker did have *both* the rod-ride merger *and* the cot-caught merger, then *lawyer* (/ˈlɔ.jɚ/) would indeed be a homophone of *lier/liar* (/ˈlaɪ.ɚ/); the presence of the /j/ isn't particularly relevant, since the diphthong /aɪ/ would end in a glide anyway. But I suspect that such speakers are fairly rare, since accents with one merger generally lack the other.

There [is also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/r/#/a%C9%AA%C9%99r/%E2%80%93/%C9%91r/_merger) a merger between /aɪər/–/ɑr/ in some Southern AmE dialects; this can merge *tire* and *tar,* but not *lier/liar* and *lawyer,* since the latter has two syllables.

(As a general reminder: even in speakers that, as you say, realize the American /ɑ/ as a central [ä], we would still transcribe that phoneme as /ɑ/; slashes are for phonemes and square brackets are for phones. I think your question may have gotten this distinction confused.)